# Reindenting Python code in Vim

Tags: python, vim, vi

I need to enclose a block of code with a for loop. As this is Python I need to take care of indenting and increment the number of tabs by one. Any easy way to do this in Vim?

Answer (score 3):

Try hitting `V` for visual line mode, select the area you want to indent, and hit `>`. Other motions besides `V` are good, too.

Comment: @Ram, `V}>` is a handy motion too. `}` will go down one block, and `>` indents the whole selection.

Comment: Also, you can use `=ip` to auto-indent within a 'paragraph' of code, or `>ip` to indent the paragraph once. There are a plethora of ways to handle indentation in Vim. Try skimming the help pages, and you'll no doubt find more.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually adjust indentation with <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>, and <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> will auto-indent a block of code.

Also, [Indenting Python with Vim](http://henry.precheur.org/vim/python) might be of help for getting some more advanced auto-indentation.

Lastly, <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> is a handy way to insert a yanked block of code, indenting it to the proper level (try yanking your block, moving the cursor to the start of your for loop, then pressing <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip224) to indent or dedent code.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way you can try is <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> from inside the block of code you want to indent. That wraps **V**isual mode **I**nside **P**aragraph, and **>** indents the selected code.

Comment: Visual mode is certainly helpful, but this is definitely not the *fastest*. `>ip` will accomplish the same thing without invoking visual mode.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other excellent answers here, I would suggest adding this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```

This will make it so that when you select text in visual mode (press <kbd>v</kbd>) and then press <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd><</kbd> it won't drop you out of visual mode.

The following lines will also make vim try to auto-indent lines for you which can be useful:

```
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

Although you will need to disable this when you paste text in or it will try to indent it.

You can turn paste mode on/off with a key, mapped like this:

```
set pastetoggle=<F6>
```

Now <kbd>F6</kbd> will toggle paste mode to allow you to paste text in without the auto-indent screwing it up.